# Render WebPart in a UserControl without containing DIV

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts

I am building a usercontrol to place webparts in my pagelayouts.

What i'm basicly doing:

```
<uc:WebPartInclude WPName="WebPartName" runat="server"</uc:WebPartInclude>
```

And this all works fine, except for one thing: It now surrounds the content of the webpart with `<div> ... </div>`.

Since i'm a sucker for clean code, this `div` has got to go ^_^

```
public class WebPartInclude : Control
{
    public string WPName = "";
    private WebControl webPartControl = null;
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        webPartControl = (WebControl)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("full path..." + WPName);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderChildren (writer);
    }
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (webPartControl != null)
            Controls.Add(webPartControl);
        ChildControlsCreated = true;
    }

    public override ControlCollection Controls
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return base.Controls;
        }
    }
}
```

So the webpart renders the following:

```
<div>
    ... webpart contents
</div>
```

And i want the surrounding divs to go, got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since there was no way of fixing it in a nice way, i just used the `HtmlTextWriter` to write the contents to a string and strip the surrounding `<div>`...`</div>`.

Problem solved, just not in a nice way.